# Javascript (Angularjs) Help. Iterate arrays in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm have one object `Data = Object{Table1:Array[2],Table2:Array[2]}`. The tables inside are ex:

```
Table1{
  Name: 'name',
  Address: 'address'
  .....
}
```

I need help iterate through this. This is response from web api (dataset)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
for(var k in data.Table1){
     console.log(data[k].Name);
}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Comment: Make sure you use the correct names of your variables. I only made a demonstrative answer that should work if is modified accordingly to any user code. You say you are using an API. Can you share the link to whom you are making the request? Also you can check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) for more help.

Comment: Resolved, there was other way to export the data from the object